# Could more arm dev-boards be on topic?

Tags: discussion

Dear fellow Raspberry Pi lovers,

I know this question has been asked before, but the last time seems to have been a while ago, and I think it might be time to consider it again.

We all love our Pi's, but there are other ARM based dev boards coming up (radxa rock, hardkernel, just to mention two) and there seems to be a huge overlap in how to set up cross-compilation chains, how to program the GPIO, how to deal with software running on x86 and segfaulting on the dev board and so on.

I have often searched for problems I have with my other dev boards, and found relevant information on the the [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) site.

I think rather than having a number of different communities potentially cannibalizing on each other, it would make more sense to have a one-stop shop for questions and answers about arm dev-boards - and I think this community has the very best position to become that one-stop shop.

Comment: I think this is probably a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45/can-we-rename-this-site-to-be-more-inclusive-of-linux-arm-hardware?rq=1) and I don't think my stance has changed. Though it will be interesting to see how much traffic [Arduino.SE](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) get.

Comment: It _is_ a duplicate question, but the site is not very well adapted for continuing an old discussion, and I think this could need another iteration.

Comment: True. I think the points in the previous answers still hold true.

Comment: While I understand these points, I also find a future with radxarock.stackexchange.com, pandaboard.stackexchange.com, beagleboard.stackexchange.com, cubieboard.stackexchange.com, odroid.stackexchange.com et cetera ad nauseum both unlikely and undesirable. Surely there are more issues and questions in common than specific ones?